# Can we extract a zip file in copy activity - Azure Datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

i have zip file i would like to uncproesss the file and get the csv file and push it to the blob.i can achive in.gz but .zip file we are not able to.

could you please assit here.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 3):

You could set binary format as source and sink dataset in ADF copy activity.Select Compression type as `ZipDefalte` following this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a46a62f2-e211-4a5f-bf96-0c0705925bcf/working-with-zip-files-in-azure-data-factory

Source:

[image]

Sink:

[image]

Test result in sink path:

[image]